# VirtualHost's DocumentRoot

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I am used to have the DocumentRoot being an absolute path to the website's DocRoot location, usually something like `/usr/local/www/apache2/data/virtualhost_name`. This is then accessible from PHP via `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` variable.

I've hosted websites on several Shared Hosting Providers and they all had it this way. Now I moved to a new provider that has it set up differently. PHP's `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` always shows `/`. I have several websites on the server in different folders but they still all show `/` as DocumentRoot.

How can I achieve the same thing on my own development server?

Comment: Are you sure it's an apache server ?

Comment: I don't think it's genuine Apache. AFAIK it may be their custom build.

Comment: http://support.nacspl.com/hesk/knowledgebase.php?article=83

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess they've CHROOT'd each site, this is common on many shared hosting providers so as not to reveal the directory structure of the server.

In a console, if you do an

```
ls -l
```

do the web-server files show as being owned by a site user? I.E. each website has it's own user account on the server. If it does I'd guess it's a CHROOT, which is easy enough to do. ([Some instructions here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/rhel-centos-apache-chrootjail-virtual-hosting.html))

Also check to see where the current file is

```
<?php
echo dirname(__FILE__);
?>
```

(That will show you the directory of the current file, if the document root is '/' then that script should return something like '/myphpfile.php')

While I haven't checked if a CHROOT would change the DOCUMENT_ROOT in PHP, I'd assume it would.

However, I don't see how having the DOCUMENT_ROOT as / would be an issue, so long as you're loading it dynamically from the $_SERVER global rather than hard-coding the directory it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I don't have access to the console unfortunately. Websites are not automatically created with a corresponding ftp account either. All I do is point a domain to a folder on the server via provider's own administration panel (it's a proprietary one). `dirname(__FILE__)` returns `/`.

Comment: Having DOCUMENT_ROOT as / is not an issue at all, I am simply wondering how can I achieve that on my local development machine? Just being curious.

Comment: @Michal If you follow the instructions at http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/rhel-centos-apache-chrootjail-virtual-hosting.html you should be able to set up CHROOT jails on your dev box, I'd guess that's all they've done as it's very common